# как сменить ip создоваемого сервера на nestJs

Tags: nestjs

Я хочу подключиться к серверу через одну локальную сеть.
но иза того-что сервер создаёться на localhost,я не могу подключиться другим устройством.
гугл не помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то у тебя уже все работает. Тебе нужно узнать локальный айпишник твоего компьютера, на котором ты всё это запускаешь и стучаться в него. Например с помощью ipconfig.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]